# Link two cells in google sheets with autofill

Tags: looker-studio

First of all I would like to thank you for your time.

I have a google data studio report that extracts data from a google sheet. The data studio sheet gets values from a google form (in the form of another tab in the sheet). Altough the cells are linked, right now I have to drag the cells in the data studio sheet to pull the values from the forms sheet. If there are no values it can´t pull anything and I would like to have real time values in the google data studio as soon as a form is filled.

Right now all I have is a simple (='Form '!C55) to pull. What I would like to do is if there is a new value in the following cell in the forms sheets then the following cell in the data studio sheets pulls it so it can go to the report in dat studio.

Cheers to all!

Comment: Is the Google sheet updating as you expect when a form is submitted?  If so, is your issue about which cells or columns to have pulled into Data Studio, or that Data Studio isn't getting updated?  I'm not sure what "if there is a new value in the following cell in the forms sheets then the following cell in the data studio sheets pulls it" means...  And sharing a sample sheet always helps me understand the issue better...  See this guide: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: I guess sharing a sample of the sheet is the best way to understand. (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ah7pBOlRnXtOGI3Amnd4sdziY_dQXcxoNbAV3eYJeCY/edit?usp=sharing)
So when a form is completed, a new line is created in the form sheet. I then want that new line to be replicated in the sheet that I use for data studio so it can go to the report. Right now I drag a line down (so if ='Form '!C55, it will pull C56) for it to pull the new line values. I would like that to be automatic. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula, in column A, after your last row of good data.  So perhaps in Dados!A91.  Note you will need to first delete everything in all of the cells below and to the right of A91, since this formula is filling everything:

```
=QUERY('Formulário '!A9:O;"select A,G,D,J,M,H,E,K,N,I,F,L,O where B <> '' ";0)
```

This queries your Formulário  sheet, and pulls all of the data starting in row 9 (since that is what you were showing with your formula before), and selects all of the correct columns in order.

Please test it out with a test form submission, to see that it works as expected, and that it is copying the correct columns, in the right order.  Let me know of any questions or issues.

I'm not positive how sheet updates work when there is no active user logged into the sheet, but I suppose when Data Studio goes to pull from Dados, it will first ensure that it has the latest data from all formulas.

[image]

### Update

To have the Max and Min values,which you say should be the same all the way down the column, add a formula like the following in the header row (row 1) of your Formulario sheet:

```
={"Cloro Max.";ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A);1,5;""))}
```

That gives a value of 1,5 for a column labelled Cloro Max.  Be sure to delete anything from row 2 down, in that same column, or the array formula gives a #REF error, since it can't put data when there is already data entered in those lower cells.

You can change the text to create a Max or Min column for each value you want, in columns Q to V.  Change the 1,5 to whatever number you want, such as 0,5 for Cloro Min.

It will always add the value(s) to each new row as it gets added from a submitted form response.

Comment: You may want to correct the format for the columns, to show "2,00", instead of "2", in column B for example.

Comment: Hi Kirk! 
Thanks a lot for the formula. It worked like a charm! I changed it to 

=QUERY('Formulário '!A2:O;"select C,G,D,J,M,H,E,K,N,I,F,L,O where B <> '' ";0)

just for convenience. I didn't realize this before but now the max. and min. values on Q are getting left behind. Do you know of a way they could be auto-filled as well? 

Cheers!

Comment: No worries, thank you for your reply. Those values are always the same to indicate the Max. and Min. values on the graph. I will share the data studio report as well as the editable test sheet. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MEgGUMn5LNRrfqWGXavtssD3QVbjfp8nGnNSL9vVREA/edit?usp=sharing

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4e055467-d060-4424-b960-707a89b83d72

So as a new line is created because of a new forms submission a new Max and Min value should also be created to accompany them in the graph. 

I am sorry, I find it hard to explain stuff like this. 

Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean that every time a new form is submitted, the Max and Min values should be recalculated, to be sure they are still correct?  Should Cloro Max be equal to the highest Cloro value submitted from a form?  In your Data Studio report, Cloro Max shows as 1.5.  Should it not be equal to 3.0, or whatever the max value in Dados columns B to E is?    Anyway, if you can tell me in words how to calculate the Max, I think I can add it into the formula.

Comment: Hi there, Kirk. Nope, they are always the same values, no calculations.Cloro max is always 1.5 (or.it can be the same as the first line of max values).  So basically a new line is added (when a new form is submitted) with the same value as the previous line.

Comment: Hi there! Wow! It worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I am getting an error in the first formula for this sheet. It says there is no column P in the Formulário tab. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lwnrBC42f_rAfEENkljuEyg3tQzFV5gcQCg-vJDkqlw/edit?usp=sharing
What do you think it could be?

Comment: Pedro, the error is in the range you have specified:  =QUERY('Formulário'!A3:O;"select C,L,.....    You need to change the A3:O to A3:P, and it should be good.  Let me know if not.

Comment: Hi there Kirk! Thank you so much. Everything worked and it was exactly what I wanted. I wish you a wonderful 2021! Cheers!